# Processing 3.3.7 - "key" variable does not always represent last key pressed

Tags: java, input, key, processing

I am trying to create a sketch that will use the WASD keys to move a character around the screen in the Processing 3.3.7 IDE.

I am having an issue when one key is released and another is pressed at the same time, the `key` variable will not change to the new input for about a second. I cut down the offending code to this:

```
void draw(){
  println(key);
}
```

With this code you can see, when you release one key and begin holding another in as close succession as possible (possibly only on the same frame) the printed value will not change for about a second (might differ depending on what your key repeat time). This is really annoying and I don't know how to get around it.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `println()` function is notoriously bad at timing, so I wouldn't trust it for micro-benchmarks like this.

Also, the `key` variable holds the last key that was interacted with, which could be the key you released instead of the key you pressed. For example, think about this sequence of events:

- I press the `a` key. The `key` variable becomes `a`.
- I press the `s` key. the `key` variable becomes `s`.
- Now I release the `a` key. the `key` variable switches back to `a`.
- I'm still holding the `s` key, so after a second, my keyboard triggers another `s` key event, switching the `key` variable to `s`.

If you want more fine-grained control over the keyboard events, I suggest using the event functions like `keyPressed()` and `keyReleased()`. You probably want to keep track of which keys are pressed using a set of variables that you set in the event functions. Here's an example:

```
boolean aPressed = false;
boolean sPressed = false;

void draw(){
  if(aPressed){
    // a is pressed
  }
  if(sPressed){
    // s is pressed
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'a'){
    aPressed = true;
  }
  else if(key == 's'){
    sPressed = true;
  }
}

void keyReleased(){
  if(key == 'a'){
    aPressed = false;
  }
  else if(key == 's'){
    sPressed = false;
  }
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input) is a tutorial on handling input events. See the **handling multiple key presses** section to read more about this approach.

Comment: This helps a lot! I'm still not sure how I would be able to implement it so that the position would move in the direction of the last key pressed.

Comment: @mono You would check the variables inside your `draw()` function, and take action depending on which key was pressed. You might also want to create your own `lastKeyPressed` variable?